# How to get entity instance when doing unit test using Symfony and PHPUnit?

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I'm trying to do a unit test in the environment as the title says. However, the method contained in the class under test requires an entity instance as an argument. So I'm trying to get the above entity in a generic homebrew test class that extends the TestCase class but I can't figure out how to do it.
I have little experience with functional testing. I used fixtures at that time, so I'm guessing that I should use fixtures this time too. Is that correct? I would appreciate if you could teach me how to do that as well.

Please let me know, even a little information.

below is the test class, and the interface of the test target.

ps. we are using nelmio/alice bundle.

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace xxx\xxxx\Tests\Customize\Server\AlladinOffice;

use Codeception\PHPUnit\TestCase;
use Customize\Service\AlladinOffice\CodeFormatter;
use Customize\Service\AlladinOffice\CustomerCode;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Eccube\Repository\CustomerRepository;
use PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\MockObject;
use Proxies\__CG__\Eccube\Entity\Customer;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;

class CustomerCodeTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerCode
     */
    private $sut;

    /**
     * @var CustomerRepository|MockObject
     */
    private $customerRepository;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $codeFormatter = new CodeFormatter();
        $this->sut = new CustomerCode($codeFormatter);
        $this->customerRepository = $this->createMock(CustomerRepository::class);
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testGetCustomerCode()
    {
        $actual = $this->sut->getCustomerCode(null);
        $expected = 1000000000;
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);

//        $customer = $this->customerRepository->findBy([], ['id' => 'ASC']);
//        dump($customer);exit();
//        $actual = $this->sut->getCustomerCode($customer);
        $customer = new Customer;
        //$customer->set

        //$this->customerRepository
            //->expects($this->any())
            //->method('find')
            //->willReturn($);
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Customize\Service\AlladinOffice;

use Eccube\Entity\Customer;

interface CustomerCodeInterface
{
    public function getCustomerCode(?Customer $customer): string;

    public function getChannelCode(?Customer $customer): string;

    public function getRankCode(?Customer $customer): string;
}
```

for example a detailed method to test.

```php
    public function getCustomerCode(?Customer $customer): string
    {
        if (!$customer) {
            return self::DEFAULT_CUSTOMER_CODE;
        }
        $customerRank = $customer->getXxxCustomer()->getCustomerRank();

        $customerChannel = $customerRank ? $customerRank->getCustomerChannel() : null;
        if (!$customerChannel || !$customerChannel->isExportToAO()) {
            return self::DEFAULT_CUSTOMER_CODE;
        }

        return $this->formatter->getCustomerCodeFromCustomerId($customer->getId());
    }
```

Comment: When you need a `Customer` entity in your test, just go ahead and create it. I don't see a reason to mock the `CustomerRepository` as your test subject doesn't depend on it. You are using the proxy that doctrine generated for your entity (`Proxies\__CG__\Eccube\Entity\Customer`). You should replace it with the actual one (`Eccube\Entity\Customer`).

Comment: @philipweinke Thank you for your comment. For the time being, the use clause of Customer was changed to `Eccube\Entity\Customer`. I've heard that I don't need a CustomerRepository, but isn't it necessary to get an entity that contains data? In the case of functional test, I think that I will read the fixture and create temporary db data, but is it not necessary in unit test?

Comment: In a unit test I'd simply create a `Customer` entity in the test with all the necessary data.

Comment: I just saw that you added the `getCustomerCode` method to your question. You might want to look into the [law of demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).